# Quadratic equation using conditional operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

Can someone explain to me step by step how this program works? It solves a quadratic equation using the conditional operator. But it's a mess.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main()
{ 
     float a, b, c, d; 
     printf("Introduce the coefficients: a,b,c\n"); 
     scanf("%f %f %f", &a,&b,&c); 
     a? d=b*b-4*a*c, d>=0? 
     printf("x1=%f\tx2=%f\n",(-b- sqrt(d))/2/a, (-b+sqrt(d))/2/a):
     printf("x1=%f+i*%f\tx2=%f-i*%f\n",-b/2/a, sqrt(-d)/2/a,-b/2/a,sqrt(-d)/2/a):
     b? printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a): c? printf("0 solutions\n"): 
     printf("identity\n"); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think the users from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ would be proud of the author ;)

Comment: It's [slightly] obfuscated, not golfed. A golfed one would be even messier!

Comment: It is a mess and does not compile. Please copy-paste the actual source code. And don't use MS Word as your source code editor...

Comment: I fixed the small problems in the code. BTW everyone can do it: just press [edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of the conditional operator is

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

It is used as a replacement for `if`-`else` statement. To understand this program, first format the conditional operators like `if`-`else` statements:

```
condition?
    expression1
:
    expression2
```

Result:

```
a?
    d=b*b-4*a*c,d>=0?
        printf("x1=%f\tx2=%f\n",(-b- sqrt(d))/2/a, (-b+sqrt(d))/2/a)
    :
        printf("x1=%f+i*%f\tx2=%f-i*%f\n",-b/2/a, sqrt(-d)/2/a,-b/2/a,sqrt(-d)/2/a)
:
    b?
        printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a)
    :
        c?
            printf("0 solutions\n")
        :
            printf("identity\n");
```

Then replace the conditional operator by `if`-`else` statements. To do that, also eliminate comma operators.

The syntax of the comma operator is

```
expression1, expression2
```

This should be replaced by a more conventional compound statement:

```
{
    expression1;
    expression2;
}
```

Result:

```
if (a)
{
    d=b*b-4*a*c;
    if (d>=0)
        printf("x1=%f\tx2=%f\n",(-b- sqrt(d))/2/a, (-b+sqrt(d))/2/a);
    else
        printf("x1=%f+i*%f\tx2=%f-i*%f\n",-b/2/a, sqrt(-d)/2/a,-b/2/a,sqrt(-d)/2/a);
}
else
{
    if (b)
    {
        printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a);
    }
    else
    {
        if (c)
            printf("0 solutions\n");
        else
            printf("identity\n");
    }
}
```

Now you can read this program.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from the top.

```
a? d=b*b-4*a*c, d>=0?
```

if a isn't 0 then set d = b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac.
If d is >= 0, then there are two roots and we print both of them.

```
printf("x1=%f\tx2=%f\n",(-b- sqrt(d))/2/a, (-b+sqrt(d))/2/a):
```

otherwise if d is <0, we have imaginary roots and they are printed using

```
 printf("x1=%f+i*%f\tx2=%f-i*%f\n",-b/2/a, sqrt(-d)/2/a,-b/2/a,sqrt(-d)/2/a)):
```

Now the last colon in this line is for if a equals 0

```
 b? printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a):
```

Now if b is non zero ( a is 0 remember?), there is only one root. If b is zero then we go to the next colon

```
c? printf("0 solutions\n"): 
 printf("identity\n");
```

I think the rest should be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

I think the functionality becomes much clearer if you use `if...else` instead of `?:`.

```
if(a != 0){
    d=b*b-4*a*c; // under the root
    if( d>=0 ){
        printf("x1=%f\tx2=%f\n",(-b- sqrt(d))/2/a, (-b+sqrt(d))/2/a);
    }
    else{
        printf("x1=%f+i*%f\tx2=%f-i*%f\n",-b/2/a, sqrt(-d)/2/a,-b/2/a,sqrt(-d)/2/a);
    }
}
else {
    if( b != 0){
        printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a);
    }
    else {
        if( c != 0){
            printf("0 solutions\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("identity\n"); 
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: `printf("x=%f\n",-b/2/a);` will divide by 0.